# How bind ENUM type by number in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is it possible to bind MySQL ENUM type by its number in PDO statement, like:

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare( "insert into `my_table` (`id`, `enum_type`) values (?, ?)");
$stm->bindParam( 1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stm->bindParam( 2, $number, PDO::PARAM_INT);
........`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PDO::PARAM_STR` should be safe for enumerated values as I believe they are stored as string/string-based data types in the database itself.

In fact, PDO defaults to `PDO::PARAM_STR` for an unspecified parameter type as is visible in its signature:

```php
 public PDOStatement::bindParam(
    string|int $param,
    mixed &$var,
    int $type = PDO::PARAM_STR,
    int $maxLength = 0,
    mixed $driverOptions = null
): bool
```

Comment: but corresponding function suppost to be `bindValue()` instead of `bindParam()`

Comment: Enums are not stored as strings: [The ENUM Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html]): "The strings you specify as input values are automatically encoded as numbers. [...] The numbers are translated back to the corresponding strings in query results.". But both PHP and MySQL will cast from/to string as expected, I see no reason to care about parameter type. The code in the question should work fine as far as I can tell.